# Problems with bibtex, references citation

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing

I am making a recopilation of different books in latex, an i am using a bibliography stored in a .bib file (10 books) as you can see below:

```
@book{americanpsy2013,
    title={Diagnostic and statistical manual of mental disorders},
    author={American Psychiatric Association},
    year={2013},
    publisher={American Psychiatric Association}
    }

@book{oxford2012,
    title={The Oxford Handbook of Traumatic Stress Disorders},
    author={J.Gayle Beck Denise M. Sloan},
    year={2012},
    publisher={Oxford University Press}
    }

@book{bryant2000,
    title={Acute Stress Disorder: A Handbook of Theory, Assessment, and Treatment},
    author={Richard A. Bryant, Allison G. Harvey},
    year={2000},
    publisher={American Psychological Association}
    }

@book{echeburua2010,
    title={¿POR QUE VICTIMA ES FEMENINO Y AGRESOR MASCULINO?: LA VIOLENCIA CONTRA LA PAREJA Y LAS AGRESIONES SEXUALES},
    author={Enrique Echeburua Ordiozola},
    year={2010},
    publisher={Piramide}
    }

@book{lorente1999,
    title={Agresión a la mujer: Maltrato, violación y acoso},
    author={Miguel Lorente Acosta, Jose Antonio Lorente Acosta},
    year={1999},
    publisher={Comares}
    }

@book{petrak2002,
    title={The trauma of sexual assault: Treatment, prevention and practice},
    author={Jenny Petrak, Barbara Hedge},
    year={2002},
    publisher={Wiley}
    }

@book{redondo2002,
    title={Delincuencia sexual: mitos y realidades},
    author={Sebastian Redondo},
    year={2002},
    publisher={Ariel}
    }

@boook{soria2000,
    title={El agresor sexual y la víctima},
    author={Miguel Angel Soria Verde, José Antonio Hernández Sánchez},
    year={2000},
    publisher={Marcombo}
    }

@book{friedman2006,
    title={Posttraumatic and Acute Stress Disorders: The Latest Assessment and Treatment Strategies},
    author={Matthew J. Friedman},
    year={2006},
    publisher={Compact Clinicals}
    }

@book{resick1996,
    title={Cognitive processing therapy for Rape Victims},
    author={Patricia A. Resick, Monica K. Schnicke},
    year={1996},
    publisher={IVPS}
}
```

i cite every one oh those books in my .tex, but my editor (gummi) only detects 8 references when i compile, so they are not shown in the order i wish here my latex code:

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\title{ \Large \textbf{Recopilacion de Libros sobre agresiones sexuales y Trastornos de estrés}}
\date{}
\maketitle

\cite{americanpsy2013}, Manual que contiene los criterios diagnosticos de los trastornos mentales y psiquiatricos existentes. \newline 

\cite{oxford2012}, Libro que trata el tema de las respuestas iniciales al trauma en personas  adultas incluye información sobre la epidemiología del trastorno de estrés agudo y el trastorno de estrés posttráumatico. \newline 

\cite{bryant2000}, Se centra en el trastorno de estrés agudo, aborda las perspectivas teóricas, las herramientas para su diagnostico y señala las evidencias empíricas en el tratamiento proporcionando ejemlos donde se aplican diferentes técnicas clinicas.\newline

\cite{echuburua2010}, En esta obra se recogen los últimos estudios y teorías cíentificas que intentan explicar el fénomeno de la agresión sexualy la violencia contra la pareja y el porque la mayoría de las víctimas son mujeres y los agresores son hombres. \newline

\cite{lorente1999}, Es un libro que aborda el fénomeno de la agresión sexual contra las mujeres en sus diferentes modalidades y su evolución a través del tiempo. \newline 

\cite{petrak2002}, Este libro se enfoca en las victimas de agresiones sexuales aportando las perspectivas teóricas e implicacionespara su tratemiento, prevención y aborda las consecuencias físicas y psicologicas de la agresión sexual.  \newline

\cite{redondo2002}, Este libro aborda la violencia sexual desde el enfoque de los delitos, presentandolo desde la perspectiva social con sus mitos y realidades,y desde la perspectiva juridica dónde se debate sobre la legislación vigente. \newline

\cite{soria200}, En esta obra se habla sobre la agresion sexual y los actores involucrados es decir el agresor y la victima intentando explicar los factores por los que una persona pueda convertirse en agresor, y los efectos de la agresión sobre la victima. \newline

\cite{friedman2006}, este libro contiene información sobre la etiología el diagnóstico, los instrumentos de evaluación, los tratamientos psicológicos y farmacológicos del trastorno de estres posttraumático, y asímismo hace una diferenciación respecto a las reacciones de estrés agudo y trastorno de estrés agudo. \newline

\cite{resick1996} Es un manual de tratamiento para victimas de agresiones sexuales mediantela terapia del procesamiento cognitivos

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{biblio.bib}
\end{document}
```

And here is the result i get:

[image]

[image]

Any solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite a few of the `author` fields of your entries contain syntax errors. Scanning over your entries, I've spotted (at least) four different types of errors.

1. Don't use commas to separate authors; instead, use the keyword `and`. E.g., instead of

   ```
   author={Patricia A. Resick, Monica K. Schnicke},
   ```

   you must write

   ```
   author={Patricia A. Resick and Monica K. Schnicke},
   ```
2. In other entries, no separator at all is provided between names. E.g., instead of

   ```
   author={J.Gayle Beck Denise M. Sloan},
   ```

   you must write

   ```
   author={J. Gayle Beck and Denise M. Sloan},
   ```

   Do note, by the way, that I've also inserted a space between "J." and "Gayle".
3. If an entry has a "corporate" author, you *must* encase the entire name in a second pair of curly braces. Thus, instead of

   ```
   author={American Psychiatric Association},
   ```

   you must write

   ```
   author={{American Psychiatric Association}},
   ```

   Without the extra pair of curly braces, BibTeX's parsing rules will make it treat the author as having given names "American" and "Psychiatric" and surname "Association". Clearly, that's not correct!
4. If a surname has two components, you have to alert BibTeX to this by using commas and placing the given names *after* the surname and a comma. Thus, instead of

   ```
   author={Enrique Echeburua Ordiozola},
   ```

   you must write

   ```
   author={Echeburua Ordiozola, Enrique},
   ```

   With Spanish and Latin American authors, it's quite common to have surnames that have two components. If you don't adjust the `author` field for this entry, BibTeX will be led to think that the author has two given names -- `Enrique` and `Echeburua` -- and one surname, `Ordiozola`. Given that this entry's key is "echeburua2010", it's safe to assume that we're dealing with an author who has a single given name and a two-component surname.

Finally, some of the entries will require two separate corrections. E.g., instead of

```
author={Miguel Lorente Acosta, Jose Antonio Lorente Acosta},
```

you will need to write

```
author={Lorente Acosta, Miguel and Lorente Acosta, Jose Antonio},
```

Observe the provision of the keyword `and` *and* the inversion of the order of surnames/given names.

Answer (score 1):

Both the missing citations are due to typos in the bibentry keys: in your LaTeX code you wrote `echuburua2010` instead of `echeburua2010` and `soria200` instead of `soria2000`.

Comment: right now it detects the ten references but the order is not correct i don't know why

Comment: @rainman - Please see the answer I've just posted. Basically, the `author` fields of almost all of your entries contain one or more syntax errors.